# Align two elements inside legend tag

Tags: html, css

How can I align the image with the text?

[image: Screenshot]

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50" width="50" height="50" />
    <label id="dettagli_ordine">Dettagli Ordine N° ${numero_ordine}</label>
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use CSS backgrounds for decorative images

Ideally you would use a background image in the CSS for the legend element. CSS backgrounds should be used for displaying decorative images.

**Aside:** The label element should not be placed in the legend, as the legend provides a caption for the entire fieldsets content and the label is for input labels.

---

**Legend styling tip:** The `<legend>` element can be horrendously difficult to style, especially cross-browser. Extra control can be obtained by using a `<span>` inside and applying the styling to that.

**Example:**

```
<legend><span>I am a legend... text</span></legend>
```

---

### Let's make this with a background image

[image: Screenshot]

### Working Example

Give the legend a height and move the text as desired with padding and line-height:

```css
legend {
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/50) no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Dettagli Ordine N° ${numero_ordine}
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `vertical-align: middle` to image element:

```css
legend img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <img src="resources/images/pacco.gif" width="50" height="50" />
    <label id="dettagli_ordine">Dettagli Ordine N° ${numero_ordine}</label>
  </legend>
  </fiedset>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img,
img + label {
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/znsux4ps/)

Answer (score -1):

Add the attribute `align="middle"` to the image

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/htj6shwt/

Comment: and using a css file ?